# Unirest node module cannot get POST data from PHP

Tags: php, node.js, unirest

I'm trying to get data sent from unirest node module via PHP. Here is my node code:

```
unirest.post('http://example.com/api')
        .headers({ 'Accept': 'application/json' })
        .send({title: 'foo',body: 'bar',userId: 1})
        .end(function (response) {
          console.log(response.body);
        });
```

My PHP page is capturing all I can think of, but I cannot get the data from the send method.

```
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json');
header('Accept: application/json');

$message = array();

$raw = file_get_contents('php://input');

$message['request'] = $_REQUEST;
$message['raw_input'] = $raw;
$message['post'] = $_POST;
$message['get'] = $_GET;
$message['server'] = $_SERVER;

$message["username"] = 'myname';
$message["password"] = 'password';

echo json_encode($message);
```

Sample response from PHP is this:

```
{ request: [],
  raw_input: [],
  post: [],
  get: [],
  server: 
   { CONTENT_LENGTH: '0',
     DOCUMENT_ROOT: '/home/example/public_html',
     GATEWAY_INTERFACE: 'CGI/1.1',
     HTTP_ACCEPT: 'application/json',
     HTTP_CONNECTION: 'keep-alive',
     HTTP_HOST: 'example.com',
     PATH: '/bin:/usr/bin',
     QS_ConnectionId: '14074674016495001612072',
     QUERY_STRING: '',
     REDIRECT_STATUS: '200',
     REMOTE_ADDR: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
     REMOTE_PORT: '58851',
     REQUEST_METHOD: 'POST',
     REQUEST_URI: '/api/',
     SCRIPT_FILENAME: 'XXXXXXXXXXX',
     SCRIPT_NAME: 'XXXXXXXXXXXX',
     SERVER_ADDR: 'XXXXXXXXXXXX',
     SERVER_ADMIN: 'XXXXXXXXX',
     SERVER_NAME: 'XXXXXXX',
     SERVER_PORT: '80',
     SERVER_PROTOCOL: 'HTTP/1.1',
     SERVER_SIGNATURE: '',
     SERVER_SOFTWARE: 'Apache',
     UNIQUE_ID: 'U@Q-iUXC5AMAAC8oJK8AAADY',
     PHP_SELF: 'XXXXXXX',
     REQUEST_TIME: 1407467401,
     argv: [],
     argc: 0 },
  username: 'myname',
  password: 'password' }
```

Any help on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
unirest.post('http://example.com/api')
.type('json')
.send({title: 'foo',body: 'bar',userId: 1})
.end(function (response) {
  console.log(response.body);
})
```